# I want to send encrypted password and decrypted password from react js to WSO2 IS 5.9.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using react JS as frontend and I want to send encrypted password to WSO2 IS 5.9.0 while using

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://x.x.x.x/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=xxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'password=abc12345' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid'
```

I want to send the password in encrypted form and decrypt the password at WSO2 IS end.
How do I perform this.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OAuth [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3), password grant can be used only if there is trust between the client and server.

The spec says as below:

> The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password)
> can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access
> token.  The credentials should only be used when there is a high
> degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the
> client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application), and when other authorization grant types are not
> available (such as an authorization code).

So it is not recommended using password grant flow in a browser client.

Comment: Mam how do i perform the above with secure transmission?

Comment: And how should i change my technique  to perform the above use case securely.

Comment: For password grant, user has to enter the credentials in the client app itself. So it is not secure unless the browser client is trusted by the server. So you can use other grant types such as authorization-code or implicit depends on your requirement. Please read the spec to know more about the authorization-code grant and implicit grant. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.1

Comment: You can follow these WSO2 IS docs https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/authorization-code-grant/, https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/implicit-grant/

Comment: if you are using a SPA application, current rent is to use authorization grant type with a public client in wso2 is. Please refer https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-09#page-5 to learn more about vulnerabilities of the implicit grant type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send the password in an encrypted form to the WSO2 IS and decrypt it in the WSO2-IS end. From the looks of is you are using the OAuth2 Password Grant, here you will have to send the password back to the server, in the same way, the user has entered it. Given that you are using a secured connection (https) you don't actually need to encrypt it in the frontend.

However, it is highly not recommended to use the Password Grant and you should look into using the [authorization code grant](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/oauth-2-0-basics-3d06bce33870). You can refer to this [[draft]OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) from the OAuth community for some best practices.